# Why does Momentjs add function not work as I expect?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I think the code below should not result in an infinite loop, but the add is not working as I expect.  There are a number of examples in SO and elsewhere, but none have helped.

```
const minDate = Moment().subtract(3, 'month');
const maxDate = Moment().add(3, 'month');

let iterDate = minDate.clone();
do {    
    iterDate.add(1, 'days');
} while (maxDate.isAfter(iterDate));
```

Comment: It's working for me. How are you importing Moment?

Comment: @ArielAlvarado same, it's working fine for me.

Comment: @ArielAlvarado Thanks for your comment.  The import is not a problem - I am able to perform other operations with Moment (eg format).  version : 2.19.2

Comment: @Upperstage set a limit to your do/while. a max limit set to 100, and just leave the loop once that is done and compare the maxDate and iterDate to see how close they are to each other. WIth a 100 loops, it should have definitely passed the maxDate if you use days.

Comment: @Upperstage check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/jd6o2eqk/

Comment: @ArielAlvarado well - I can't argue with that!  many thanks for the fiddle.  At least I can proceed knowing Moment is not the culprit.  Many thanks to you and @kemicofa!

Comment: @ArielAlvarado If you post an answer - something that reads essentially like your comment above - I will accept it.  

My problem involved code (I did not include above) where I was attempting to determine whether iterDate was the first day of a month.  I was using iterDate.startOf - a method that mutated iterDate.

Comment: Glad it helped. No need to post an answer though :)